# NSAnimationContext issue: no animation with isHidden property

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-animation

I have the following view structure:

[image]

In the `Date Stack View`, I want to hide/unhide the `Advanced Stack View`in an animated way (like the height was reduced to zero).
I searched a lot for a solution and I came up with this:

```
dateStackView.wantsLayer = true
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in

        context.duration = 0.5
        context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
        advancedDateStackView.animator().isHidden = true
        self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()

        }, completionHandler: nil)
```

But it does not work --> no animation
However, if I replace:
`advancedDateStackView.animator().isHidden = true`
by
`advancedDateStackView.animator().alphaValue = 0`,
I can see a fadeout animation for the advancedDateStackView. Which is not the desired behaviour, but proves the animation can work.

I also tried `self.advancedDateStackView.animator().frame.size.height = 0`
but no animation either.

Any help would be appreciated, I struggle to find a solution.

Thanks!!

**EDIT** to answer the comment below saying my question is a duplicate: Here my code works and allows me to perform a transition with `alphaValue`. However, what I need, and what does not work, is to perform a transition on `isHidden`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa: NSView Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456080/cocoa-nsview-animation)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. As I mention in the question, the animation works with the alphaValue parameter, but not with the isHidden ...