# Delay before beginning animation of NSView (AppKit)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

The following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456080/how-to-fade-out-a-nsview-with-animation/62294469) shows how to do a fade-out for `NSView` in Swift:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
    context.duration = 1
    self.view.animator().alphaValue = 0
}, completionHandler: {
    self.view.isHidden = true
    self.view.alphaValue = 1
})
```

I am using this code to display a status notification -> i.e. the text appears, stays for around a few seconds, and then fades out. Is there a way to delay the start of the fade out to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to delay the start of the fade out to accomplish this?

One way is to use [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer) to run your animation after whatever delay you choose. For example, you could pass a block containing your code to [`+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/2091889-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval), and once the interval expires the block will run.